# How can i connect access database on console application?

Tags: c#

I want to update the database on my console application.

but here has an error:

```
The type name ‘OleDbConnection’ could not be found in the namespace ‘System.Data.OleDb’. 
This type has been forwarded to assembly ‘System.Data.OleDb, Version=4.0.1.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35’ 
Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
```

I can easily reach datas from form application but when i try it on console application, i can not.
there is my code:

```
using System;

using System.Data;

using System.Data.OleDb;


namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=.\botbase.accdb");
        }

    }
}
```

there is the photo:

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Don't post pictures of code or error messages here.

Comment: In Solution Explorer there is a Reference Tab.  Right click "Reference" and Add Reference : Net.  You should be see Reference.  So right click ConsoleApp1 and Add Reference : Net : System.Data

Comment: i looked but there is not : 
[link](https://prnt.sc/ru55ia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using `.NET Core` and not the `.NET Framework`?

So you probably have to use the `.NET Platform Extensions` (available as NuGet package):
[System.Data.OleDb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.OleDb)

The [issue-comment that announces it](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23321#issuecomment-502413964):

> Everyone,
>
> Now that System.Data.OleDb is available on NuGet.org, it would be great if you could  take it for a spin on .NET Core 3.0 preview 6. If you have an existing application,  sample code, or a test that was blocked from working on .NET Core for lack of this functionality, please try now. We are hoping to get your help to cover a variety of OLEDB providers and scenarios, so we can identify any issues with the port before RTM.
>
> Thanks!

Another really useful package for Windows dependent features:
[Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

`OleDbConnection` is in the `System.Data.Common.DbConnection` namespace.

Add a `using` clause to the top of your file for that namespace.

Comment: i added top of my codes : 
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Common.dbConnection;

but still not

Comment: @SydneyfunnelAllinOne Check your references.